# Method not found: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceModel.Service.set_IsSLBPartialGS(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceModel.Expression)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

Since a while I am facing the following error when trying to launch any kind of application with the Azure Emulator:

```
Microsoft Azure Tools: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceModel.Service.set_IsSLBPartialGS(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceModel.Expression)'.
```

A restart of my machine usually solves this for a while, but I tend to run into this problem daily, and if I see this warning once, there's no way to get around it without a reboot.

Sadly, I can also not find a lot of documentation, if any.

I am using the Azure Tools V2.9.

Does anyone have a solution, or at least a hint as to what this could be?

Comment: Really would like to know this too! This is getting annoying. I started getting this recently and noticed this last Friday you posted it the same day. Is this caused by an azure update?

Comment: @Deinonychus I wouldn't exclude that. I recently setup my device again and had this happen since then, so I guess I also got the latest versions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Problem:**

The Azure SDK v2.9 is shipped with a mismatched version of assemblies.  One of the assemblies is missing a setter for the property called IsSLBPartialGS.

**Fix:**

Copy the 2 assemblies Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceModel.dll and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceModel.Comon.dll from:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Emulator"

to:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Emulator\devfabric"

Note that you'll need admin rights for this operation.  I recommend making a backup before overwriting any assemblies.

**How the I found the fix:**

I wrote my own decompiler and symbol inspector to in order to compare assemblies and their contents.  After comparing multiple folders, I found that the Microsoft.Windows.Azure.ServiceModel.dll in the Emulator folder has the AssemblyFileVersion:
`1.0.6696.103 (rd_sm.180206-1102)`

while the one in the DevFabric folder is version:
`1.0.6696.47 (rd_sm.160421-1505)`

Note that both `AssemblyVersion`'s are the same (as shown in .NetReflector to be 1.0.0.0), however the `AssemblyFileVersions` are different.  Looking further between the differences in the decompiled code from my program, I found that the assembly in the DevFabric (which is a slightly older version) is missing some key classes/methods/properties including the following:
[See picture of code difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6ipj.png)

Comment: You just saved my colleagues and me so many hours, thanks a lot! This seems to work!

Answer (score 6):

I experienced this issue starting recently, and was able to resolve it by reverting `Azure Data Lake and Stream Analytics Tools` to version `2.3.3000.2` -- the update to `2.3.7000.2` on 3/25/19 seems to have introduced the issue.

Comment: Since I ended up back here... it's not fixed  in `2.3.8000.0`.

Comment: I have to agree, I am still facing it. Although it looked stable for a while after doing what you suggested

Comment: Updating to Tools version 2.3.9000.0 helps for me

Comment: I have experienced the issue even with 2.3.9000.0 when trying to F5 a Cloud Service project in emulator. Uninstall solve the issue for me.

Comment: @ViktorZ Oh, I see, but the next stepos works for me:
1. Close MSVS (I use MSVS 2015)
2. Close emulators
3. Open IIS Manager and delete a site for a web role
4. Start MSVS again, open solution, start debugging
I use Win 10 and have installed MSVS 2019, may be it related…

Comment: @ViacheslavIvanov - this worked in my case (MSVS 2019, no IIS so just did steps 1,2,4)

Answer (score 3):

For me, it was just because I didn't start VS2019 as Administrator. Closed the solution and started it with Admin privilege then error went away.

Answer (score 2):

Only Visual Studio Repairing resolved the problem for me.

I had the same eror, but it shows me the error when I tried to start debugging 2 and more applications at the same time.

To perform the repairing open Visual Studio Installer and find Repair option there.

Updated:
when I installed Resharper back - I started to get the error, after I uninstalled - everything started to work.

Comment: Thanks, suspending ReSharper solves problem for me.